# Regex for Google analytics advanced segment based on custom variable value

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Trying to create an advanced segment (include) using regex (or any other filter mechnanism, contains with just the substring isn't working either) which uses the value of the custom variable value.

It ought to be straightforward, but it's driving me insane. I currently have this regex:

.*CLAS_LIBRARIES.*

which rightly matches a custom variable value of:

HOME/CLASMAIN/CLAS_LIBRARIES/

but when I apply the segment and then browse the custom variable values in the report, it contains values like:

- HOME/
- /museumcollections/
- HOME/MAPS/

Tried wrapping it like this:

.*(CLAS_LIBRARIES).*

(.*)(CLAS_LIBRARIES)(.*)

to no avail.

What the hell is going on, and am I an idiot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the scope of your custom variable? Can multiple sessions have different values?

Advanced segments will return any data that matches your query (e.g. in case of creating a segment for a specific page, GA will return data for all user activity which included that specific page as part of their navigation).

Comment: You are, of course, absolutely right as I now realise. Segment filter tests against the visit, not the pageview. I was isolating traffic for the visits that included HOME/CLASMAIN/CLAS_LIBRARIES/ URLs, but within the course of those visits, they also viewed other URLs and it's those are showing up. If think filtering a custom report instead of a segment is what's needed.